# How can I calculate this matrix differentiation?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am studying about the Matrix Differentiation.

I don't know if this red box differential metric, which is how it is calculated.

[image]

Comment: Thoughts? Efforts? Pictures of problems generally get less favorable responses. Users tend to prefer people putting the effort into typing up the problems and showing what they've tried/thoughts. If you're wondering how to type a question up in this fashion check out the following link.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Vincent I do not think that "showing what you've tried" is relevant here - they are just wanting to understand someone's mathematical writing! *However*, I do think that the question is unclear. Perhaps, 최보경, you could add a paragraph explaining your problem a bit more?

Comment: @user1729 
Thank you for your kindness
I'm reading a paper called Maximum likelihood linear regression, 
In this paper appeared in the formula corresponding to the red box. 
However, this paper has been omitted in the process of solving this equation. 
So I wonder solving process of the formula contained in the red box. (T.T)

Comment: You should edit your question to say this. Also, you would get a better response if you typed your working out here (I am presuming you used $\LaTeX$ to do the working which you've posted?)

Comment: Also, @Vincent, the post is *precisely* the OPs thoughts and working!

Comment: @user1729 
I solved the above problem ~
Thanks for your help !!!